# Why don't we override the methods in Spring CRUD Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am looking into Spring data and one thing I've noticed is that we're able to perform CRUD operations just by creating an interface which implements the CRUD repository and by default, we're given access to generated queieres to the db via the method name.

I thought whenever we implement an Interface, we need to provide an implementation to the methods. So why don't we override anything when we use an interface which implements from the CrudRepository interface?

Comment: Spring Data automatically generates an implementation of the interface for you - you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: Does it get generated on runtime. Where am i able to find the implementation for it?

Comment: It gets generated at runtime and it's not generated in the form of source code, but probably with Java's dynamic proxy mechanism or with a bytecode engineering library such as cglib. So there is no source code of the implementation to see.

Comment: @Jesper does sound like an answer to me

Comment: If you want to see the code behind the CRUD Repository. Do `Ctrl + Click` on `CrudRepository<T, ID>`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the goals of Spring Data is to make database access easy, without the need to manually write a lot of boilerplate code.

Traditionally, one of the things developers commonly did when working with a database is write [DAOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (database access objects) with methods, where each method would do a specific query. Such methods would typically be [boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) - simple, repetitive code that's a lot of work to write and maintain and that doesn't contain any business logic.

When you use Spring Data, all this code is automatically generated for you. The only thing you have to do is specify in a repository interface what query you want to do, and Spring Data then interprets the meaning of the method name to automatically generate the code that does the query for you.

That saves you a lot of time and helps you a great deal to keep your own code concise; it also helps with the prevention of bugs.

The implementation of a Spring Data repository interface is generated automatically at runtime. This isn't done by generating source code which is compiled - behind the scenes Spring Data directly generates the bytecode of the implementation of the interface.